# Visual Stuio - Error TS1005 'Character' Expected

Tags: typescript, visual-studio

I have been surfing the web for almost 5 hours trying to solve this issue. Current answers addressing this questions aren't solving my problem.

I have updated `tsc` version to latest `version 3.7.3` but this issue is persisting on visual studio 2017 community.

`typescript.d.ts` file located in `node_modules/typescript/lib/` seems to be having over 3347 errors according to visual studio, but i realized they're all not `TS1005`, others existing are `TS2307`, `TS2304` etc, and they're all referring to the same file.

Here's some of the errors repeating themselves, on different sections of the page.

Error 1005: `Error TS1005(TS) '(' expected. Location: Property\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.d.ts`

Error 2304: `TS2304 (TS) Cannot find name 'FileReference'. Property\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.d.ts 4960`

What am I doing wrong here?

Here's my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "./wwwroot/_compiled",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "typeRoots": [ "node_modules/@types" ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot/dist",
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Visual studio is almost certainly using an older version of TS that doesn't support features in 3.7. I'm not sure if there's a way to tell VS2017 to use the workspace version like there is for VSCode

Comment: I see, let me research on that matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just managed to locate the typescript version that Visual Studio is using, I changed it to lastest. Most of the errors disappeared.

[image]

Only errors related to webpack were left, Finally. Now I am able to filter only errors I have control of.